# Using Postman to test POST with .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I am testing out a new .net app that will use JWT to create tokens for site access.  I have a simple Model:

```
    namespace JWTAuth.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I have a simple controller right now that accepts a POST:

```
    namespace JWTAuth.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]User userParam)
        {
            var user = _userService.Authenticate(userParam.UserName, userParam.Password);
            if (user == null)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password incorrect." });

            return Ok(User);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var users = _userService.GetAll();
            return Ok(users);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use postman I am using the POST method with the following raw JSON in the body:

```
    {
  "id": 0,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "userName": "test",
  "password": "user",
  "token": null
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the constructor I will step into the constructor just fine, but when I goes to POST the data I keep getting:

```
{
    "": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

The URL I'm hitting is:
          https://localhost:44378/api/users/authenticate

I have tried a variety of changes in the JSON to get this to post and I can't get past this error.  I have looked around in stackoverflow as well as Google to find a solution and I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `JSON (application/json)` type of body content

[image: Body type]

Or set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` manually

[image: Content-Type header]

Comment: BINGO!  Thanks.  Setting the JSON(application/json) fixed the problem.  Thanks.